# Babel file is copied without being transformed

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have this code:

```
"use strict";

import browserSync from "browser-sync";
import httpProxy from "http-proxy";

let proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
```

and I have installed `babel-core` and `babel-cli` globally via npm. The point is when I try to compile with this on my terminal:

```
babel proxy.js --out-file proxified.js
```

The output file gets copied instead of compiled (I mean, it's the same as the source file).

What am I missing here?

Comment: does the `let` change to `var` but the `import` statements remain?

Comment: For newer versions of react , use the new babel modules : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53927457/6665568   . It has better error messages and supports new features of react.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Babel is a transformation framework. Pre-6.x, it enabled certain transformations by default, but with the increased usage of Node versions which natively support many ES6 features, it has become much more important that things be configurable. By default, Babel 6.x does not perform any transformations. You need to tell it what transformations to run:

```
npm install babel-preset-env
```

and run

```
babel --presets env proxy.js --out-file proxified.js
```

or create a `.babelrc` file containing

```
{
    "presets": [
        "env"
    ]
}
```

and run it just like you were before.

`env` in this case is a preset which basically says to compile all standard ES* behavior to ES5. If you are using Node versions that support some ES6, you may want to consider doing

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["env", { "targets": { "node": "true" } }],
    ]
}
```

to tell the preset to only process things that are not supported by your Node version. You can also include browser versions in your targets if you need browser support.

Comment: this is useful. why didnt they put this in the documentation? is it safe to install babel-preset globally?

Comment: @kidcapital The docs do include this, but only as a side note it seems. I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to get babel 6.0 configured properly back when it was first released.

Comment: The gist of this post has been added as an info box at the Setup page per [PR#72](https://github.com/babel/babel.github.io/pull/572/files). A very minor improvement, but you gotta start somewhere! Thanks Logan.

Comment: So much for convention over configuration ... so out of the box Babel does nothing - just copies files?

Comment: Please ask a new question with all of the info about your setup so someone can answer it.

Comment: My `.babelrc` needed to look like this to work: `{ "presets": ["react", "ES2015"] }`

Comment: Yup, `es2015` does not include any other stuff like JSX parsing, you'd need `react` for that.

Comment: It's working in my env (node v4.4.4 + babel v6.18.0). If one wants have babel to produce es5 code from es6, he/she would do this. Thanks much!

Comment: It coverts from ES6 To ES5 but doesn't create the file with --ouput-file

Comment: I had to do this also for node 6.

Comment: Edited to remove specific node version references and to recommend `preset-env` instead of `preset-es2015`.

Comment: Hi can you show how to di this with the babel-core.transform runtime ?

Answer (score 5):

Most of these answers are obsolete. `@babel/preset-env` and `"@babel/preset-react` are what you need (as of July 2019).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with a different cause:

The code I was trying to load was not under the package directory, and Babel does not default to transpiling outside the package directory.

I solved it by moving the imported code, but perhaps I could have also used some inclusion statement in the Babel configuration.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? my frontend code is not "under the package directory" either and it works fine. My server code contains "import" but babel-cli is not resolving those ...

Comment: Hmm, not sure what to elaborate on? Babel was not transpiling. Try looking at all your sources of Babel config…

Comment: the problem I'm trying to solve is that my server files are orgnanized in several folders: I have servers.js, then /api/...stuff... When I run from memory, each "import" or "require" in those files are being resolved dynamically. When I run babel from the command line, I only outputs a single file, but doesn't resolve the relative imports, so I cannot use that to run my server ...

Answer (score 3):

First ensure you have the following `node modules`:

`npm i -D webpack babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-2 babel-loader`

Next, add this to your Webpack *config* file (`webpack.config.js`) :

```
// webpack.config.js
...
module  :  {
  loaders  :  [
    {
      test    :  /\.js$/,
      loader  :  'babel',
      exclude :  /node_modules/,
      options :  {
        presets  :  [ 'es2015', 'stage-2' ] // stage-2 if required
      } 
    } 
  ]
}
...
```

References:

- https://gist.github.com/Couto/6c6164c24ae031bff935
- https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/214

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

## As of `2020, Jan`:

### STEP 1: Install the `Babel presets`:

`yarn add -D @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react`

### STEP 2: Create a file: `babelrc.js` and add the `presets`:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  // ...
}
```

### STEP 3:- Install the `babel-loader`:

`yarn add -D babel-loader`

### STEP 4:- Add the loader config in your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
{
//...
  module: [
    rules: [
      test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
      loader: require.resolve('babel-loader')
    ]
  ]
//...
}
```

Good Luck...

Comment: Hi Akash, I have legacy react app in which we used types in .js file extention when I try to make build using webpack 4 it gives me error unexpected tokens and etc  previously we are using                 test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                query: {
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                    presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
                } 
Please help me to fix that I tried above things but no luck

Comment: Hi @MuhammadAsad, can you try `stage-2` instead of `stage-0`?

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-node5

npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react
```

...and then creating a `.babelrc` with the presets:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "node5",
    "react"
  ]
}
```

...resolved a very similar issue for me, with babel `3.8.6`, and node `v5.10.1`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-node5
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react

Answer (score 1):

Same error, different cause:

Transpiling had worked before and then suddenly stopped working, with files simply being copied as is.

Turns out I opened the `.babelrc` at some point and Windows decided to append `.txt` to the filename. Now that `.babelrc.txt` wasn't recognized by babel. Removing the `.txt` suffix fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

fix your .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "ES2015"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In year 2018:**

Install following packages if you haven't yet:

```
npm install babel-loader babel-preset-react
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['es2015','react']  // <--- !`react` must be part of presets!
        }
      }
    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ultimate solution**

I wasted 3 days on this

```
import react from 'react' unexpected identifier
```

I tried modifying `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` files, and adding `.babelrc`, installing & updating packages via `npm`, I've visited many, many pages but nothing has worked.

---

What worked? Two words: npm start. That's right.

**run the**

```
npm start
```

**command in the terminal** to launch a local server

...

(mind that it might not work straight away but *perhaps* only after you do some work on npm because before trying this out I had deleted all the changes in those files and it worked, so **after you're really done, treat it as your last resort**)

---

I found that info on [this neat page](https://typeofweb.com/2018/01/29/tworzenie-aplikacji-react-js-dzieki-create-react-app/). It's in Polish but feel free to use Google translate on it.