# Babel does not seem to transpile

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to use babel to transpile ES6, but it's not working. I'm doing a very basic example, so here must be something obvious I am missing.

I installed babel via npm:

```
$ npm install -g babel-cli
```

My file, `test.js`:

```
const input = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(input.map(item => item + 1)); // [2, 3, 4]
```

The command I'm running:

```
$ babel test.js
```

And the output:

```
const input = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(input.map(item => item + 1)); // [2, 3, 4]
```

Note that it's unchanged. I expect it to be transpiled...what could be going on here?

Comment: Already answered--see documentation for Babel 6. Try something like `$ npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-es2015`.

Comment: Could you point me to the docs on this? The install page just says `$ npm install babel-cli` (here: https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/)

Comment: Also, `$ npm install -g babel-cli babel-preset-es2015` doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440405/babel-file-is-copied-without-being-transformed.

Comment: This question is literally asked multiple times a day. It shouldn't be too hard to use the search and find a solution before asking a new question.

Comment: The documentation is wrong and search did not bring up anything. Emperically, since it's being asked multiple times a day, it *is* hard to find a solution