# babelify transform not transpiling fat arrow

Tags: javascript, browserify, babeljs

After a fresh install browserify, the following is not working for me:

`browserify main.js -o bundle.js -t babelify`

The content of `main.js` is:

```
var x = () => { return 5 }
console.log(x);
```

It returns with the fat arrow intact, which causes an error in the browser:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
var x = () => {
  return 5;
};
console.log(x);

},{}]},{},[1]);
```

What step am I missing?

### UPDATE

To add to Felix King's answer, for posterity, the spacing between the brackets `] ]` maters: I had tried the same thing before with `]]` and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you also install the latest version of `babelify`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`babelify` README](https://github.com/babel/babelify/blob/v7.2.0/README.md):

> As of [Babel 6.0.0](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/) there are **no plugins included by default**. For babelify to be useful, you must also include some [presets](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets) and/or [plugins](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#transform).
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> $ browserify script.js -o bundle.js \
> -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]
> ```

---

Related: [Babel file is copied without being transformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440405/babel-file-is-copied-without-being-transformed)

Comment: Weird, I had tried that before without success, but it works now.  I must have gotten something trivial wrong.  Thanks!