# Parse Failure When Using File with ES6 Syntax as Webpack Entry Point

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to use Webpack to transpile some source files written using ES6 syntax and JSX. However, when I run the Webpack command, I get the following error.

```
ERROR in ./app/App.jsx
Module parse failed: ./app/App.jsx Line 5: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 'use strict';
| 
| import React from 'react';
| import { RouteHandler } from 'react-router';
| 
 @ multi main
```

As you'll see below, I'm using the babel-loader, yet it seems to me that the loader isn't able to handle the 'import' syntax. Any idea why this might be happening?

Here's a look at our basic file structure.

```
--/app
----/components
------/shared
--------NavigationBar.js
----App.jsx
--webpack.config.js
--package.json
```

Here's our package.json file.

```
// package.json

{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^1.13.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-router": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here's our webpack.config.js file.

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + '/app',
  entry: './App.jsx',

  output: {
    filename: 'app.js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
};
```

And finally, here's /app/App.jsx

```
// App.jsx

'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { RouteHandler } from 'react-router';

import NavigationBar from './components/shared/NavigationBar';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavigationBar />
        <RouteHandler />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Let me know if you need any more information to diagnose the problem. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Babel file is copied without being transformed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440405/babel-file-is-copied-without-being-transformed)

Comment: This question is asked almost daily. It shouldn't be difficult for you to find relevant information using the search or browsing the babeljs tag.

Comment: @FelixKling I actually had tried this solution, and it didn't fix the problem. Since the problem wasn't resolved after specifying the presets, I removed them. After some more intense visual inspection of my code in the webpack config file, I also discovered that I had a typo in the regex test for file extensions. You see, my entry point was app/App.jsx, but the regex test `/\.js?$/` didn't match the .jsx extension. So my entry point wasn't being transpiled. After fixing that, I discovered that the missing presets were also a problem. Thanks for the help though, everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from Babel 6 you need to declare the presets manually, check [this](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6/).

Basically, in the root of your project you need a `.babelrc` with the following content:

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "react" ]
}
```

And the corresponding npm modules in package.json:

```
// package.json

{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --inline",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^1.13.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-router": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Banged my head against this for a while too! My problem ended up being similar. The JS file I was working in wasn't *actually* being picked up by webpack.

In my case, I was developing in a new source directory I hadn't told webpack about. To tell it, I just had to add another entry to the `include` key of my Babel-ified JS loader configuration.

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loaders: ['babel?' + JSON.stringify({
      plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
      presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
    })],
    include: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'another_source_directory')], // <-- this
  }
]
```