# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: gulp, webpack, babeljs

babel compile es6 about Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import.
I use webpack + gulp ,but throw  Unexpected token import.How to solve this problem?

**index.jsx**

```
'use strict';
import React from 'react';
```

**package.json**

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.15",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-webpack": "^1.5.0",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-tools": "^0.13.3",
    "vinyl-named": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9"
  }
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
 var gulp = require('gulp');
 var webpack = require('gulp-webpack');
 var named = require('vinyl-named');
 gulp.task('dev', function() {
    return gulp.src('app/scripts/index.jsx')
        .pipe(named())
        .pipe(webpack({
            watch : true,
            module: {
              loaders: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    loader: 'babel',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                    }
                }
              ]
            },
           output : {
               filename : '[name].jsx',
           },
           resolve: {
            alias: { localforage: 'localforage/dist/localforage.min' }
           }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/dist/'));
 });
```

Comment: I take out the `'use strict'`.but it's not working.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions! [tag:babel] is for questions about a Python library with that name.

Comment: @DavinTryon: That's simply wrong.

Comment: @FelixKling ok, I thought it might be worth a shot.  I've had problems with code statements above `import`.   I didn't know if 'use strict'; was different.

Comment: @FelixKling, sorry! save note!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Babel file is copied without being transformed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440405/babel-file-is-copied-without-being-transformed)