# Babel command not found

Tags: npm, babeljs

I have installed the babel-cli tool as explained by the Babel ['getting started'](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_cli) page.

From a terminal inside my project folder:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli
```

After this, there is a node_modules directory with a babel-cli folder, but there is no package.json created. npm also shows the following error:

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/MyName/Sites/Tutorials/Babel2/package.json
```

When trying to run babel, I get this:

```
babel src -d lib
-bash: babel: command not found
```

I have the latest version of nodejs/npm installed. I have run npm update -g, and I have edited my **.bash_profile** file to include:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/MyName/npm/bin
export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH
```

I have not experienced this with other npm tools such as browserify. Why is babel not recognized?

Comment: You can see how to get started with babel-cli here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34483748/running-babel-cli-from-npm-script-not-working/34484065

Comment: If you're using fish, try https://github.com/oh-my-fish/plugin-node-binpath

Comment: In my case I had to reinstall my node_modules:

`rm -rf ./node_modules && npm i`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

There are two problems here. First, you need a `package.json` file. Telling npm to install without one will throw the `npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory` error. In your project directory, run `npm init` to generate a `package.json` file for the project.

Second, local binaries probably aren't found because the local `./node_modules/.bin` is not in `$PATH`. There are some solutions in [How to use package installed locally in node_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9679932/503463), but it might be easier to just wrap your babel-cli commands in npm scripts. This works because `npm run` adds the output of `npm bin` (`node_modules/.bin`) to the `PATH` provided to scripts.

Here's a stripped-down example `package.json` which returns the locally installed babel-cli version:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "babel-version": "babel --version"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.6.5"
  }
}
```

Call the script with this command: `npm run babel-version`.

Putting scripts in package.json is quite useful but often overlooked. Much more in the docs: [How npm handles the "scripts" field](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)

Comment: After considering the other answers, and exploring messing with my `~/.profile` file to ensure I can call the packages in the local `node_modules`, I've concluded the `scripts` area of `package.json` is the best option. You won't need to tell your co-workers to change their profiles or make alias, your scripts will just work.

Comment: I'm using Yarn (work requirement) and most fixes I've seen for this issue use npx. The "./node_modules/.bin is not in $PATH" fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: If you're running in docker, then after npm install, the files might not end up in the node_modules (known linux weirdness, UID/GID??). Then, ofc, the binaries aren't found in node_modules/bin.

Answer (score 47):

When I found this question, I was looking for

```
$ npm install -g babel-cli
```

Comment: You should never have to use sudo with npm. Try using nvm to manage your node versions.

Comment: ```npm install -g babel-cli``` Will work without sudo.

Comment: you should use `sudo` with `npm install -g babel-cli` to access this file /usr/local/lib/node_modules, else you'll be denied.

Comment: The @babel/cli docs recommends against installing babel-cli globally (to avoid conflicts with other projects using different versions of babel, and to improve portability)

Answer (score 17):

Installing `babel` globally solves this issue:

```
npm install -g @babel/core @babel/cli
```

However, **it is not encourage to install dependencies globally because they won't have their versions managed on a per-project basis.**

You should install your dependencies locally, as suggested on `babel`'s [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli):

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli
```

The downside is that this gives you no fast/convenient way to invoke local binaries interactively (in this case `babel`). `npx` gives you a great solution:

```
npx babel --version
```

This will run your local installation of `babel`. Additionally, if you want to avoid typing `npx`, you can configure the [*shell auto fallback*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx#shell-auto-fallback), and then just run:

```
babel --version
```

---

**Note:** it is important to create a file `.babelrc`, at your project's root, in which you specify your babel configuration. As a starting point you can use [`env-preset`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) to transpile to ES2015+:

```
npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev
```

In order to enable the preset you have to define it in your .babelrc file, like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Comment: As suggested by the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli#install) you need to install @babel/core and @babel/cli irrespective of their versions.

Answer (score 12):

This is common issue and its looking for `.cmd` file from your root directory where you installed `babel-cli`. Try the below command.

> ./node_modules/.bin/babel.cmd

Once you are able to see your source code in the command prompt. Your next step is to install one more npm module `babel-preset-es2015`.

Follow the below answer to install `babel-preset-es2015` and see why babel need this.

[babel-file-is-copied-without-being-transformed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33440848/5696335)

Answer (score 12):

To install version 7+ of Babel run:

```
npm install -g @babel/cli
npm install -g @babel/core
```

Comment: That's what helped me!

Answer (score 6):

This is what I've done to automatically add my local project `node_modules/.bin` path to `PATH`. In `~/.profile` I added:

```
if [ -d "$PWD/node_modules/.bin" ]; then 
    PATH="$PWD/node_modules/.bin"
fi
```

Then reload your bash profile: `source ~/.profile`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Deleted the `nodemodules` folder and opened command prompt as administrator and then ran `npm install`.

All packages installed fine.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me e.g.

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel --version
./node_modules/.bin/babel src/main.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add quotes around the path to your babel file as below

"./node_modules/.bin/babel" --help

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you want to use cmd commands,you have two ways.
First, install it at gloabl environment.
The other way is `npm link`.
so, try the first way: `npm install -g babel-cli`.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to install the cli globally.

Since [Babel 7 was released](https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/08/27/7.0.0#major-breaking-changes) the namespace has changed from `babel-cli` to `@babel/cli`, hence:

```
npm install --global @babel/cli
```

You'll likely still encounter errors for `@babel/core` so:

```
npm install --global @babel/core
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the very same problem, tried out really everything that I could think of. Not being a fan of installing anything globally, but eventually had to run
`npm install -g babel-cli`,
which solved my problem.
Maybe not the answer, but definitely a possible solution...

Answer (score 0):

For those using Yarn as their package manager instead of npm:

```
yarn global add babel-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me inside package.json as an npm script but it does seem to take to long grabbing the packages even though I have them as dev dependancies. It also seems too long.

```
"babel": "npx -p @babel/cli -p @babel/core babel --version"
```

What end up solving it was much simpler but funny too

```
npm install
```

I thought I ran that already but I guess somethings needed to be rebuilt. Then just:

```
"babel": "babel --version"
```