# How do I check which babel version is on my windows 10 OS?

Tags: babeljs

I need help to find which version of Babel is on my Windows Machine. I have installed it using

```
npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env.
```

How do I check which version is on my Windows OS?

Answer (score 5):

After you finish installing Babel, your package.json file should look like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

So you can find your Babel version in this configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this at the command line:

```
npm list babel-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also check the version of `babel-cli` by finding the **babel-cli** folder in `node_modules` and looking at the `version` property of the `package.json` that is at the base of that folder.

If babel-cli was installed globally via `-g` flag of `npm install`, you could check the version by executing command `babel --version`.

Hopefully the helps!

Answer (score 2):

As the babel is updated to babel 7,
check using
`npm list @babel/cli`
or
`npm list @babel/core`

Answer (score 1):

possibly your local `./node_modules/.bin` is not in `$PATH` check out
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421513/babel-command-not-found) previous question for further info.

Answer (score -1):

`babel --version`

You can figure this out by typing in the command line:

`babel --help`, look over the output and you can see other options that you might need.

Good luck