# how to install babel-cli babel-preset-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs, babel-preset-env

I tried all possible way to install `babel-cli babel-preset-react`

Things I tried `npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-react`

but when I check `babel -h`

It shows `The program 'babel' can be found in the following packages:`

I refer this question also but doesn't work [Babel command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421513/babel-command-not-found/34491859#34491859)

Comment: have you saved it in a local directory which contains package.json, if yes, then try adding `babel -h` inside scripts in package.json  `babelh: babel -h` and run using `npm run babelh`

Comment: [package.json](https://i.imgur.com/sm4s3Nh.png) this is my package.json file. And I tried `babel -h` but same error

Comment: Since you write babel in script, you would use `npm run babel -h`

Comment: yes I wrote now it is running `babel -h` this command. but this not working `babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=env,react --watch`

Comment: if babel is install then why i am getting this error `The program 'babel' can be found in the following packages:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to run the babel command, you need to either install babel globaly or run it from `package.json` by saving it in scripts

```
scripts: {
   babelCmd: "babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --presets=env,react --watch"
}
```

and run using

```
npm run babelCmd
```

If you want to run the babel command directly, you need to install like

```
npm install -g babel-cli babel-preset-react
```