# React.js : SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level while importing react-pure-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use react-pure-grid in my web app.

I just imported it after installing it as described in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pure-grid

```
import {Container, Row, Col} from 'react-pure-grid';
```

After that, my browser says:

```
SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level
```

Please help me!

Comment: Are you importing 'react-pure-grid' in top of the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In webpack how do I fix 'import declarations may only appear at top level of a module'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023369/in-webpack-how-do-i-fix-import-declarations-may-only-appear-at-top-level-of-a-m)