# crypto js :global module exports may only appear at top level angular typings

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, cryptojs

I'm trying to integrate crypto-js with my angular 2 app.

**Global module exports may only appear at top level angular typings.**

I have read the below contents
[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023369/in-webpack-how-do-i-fix-import-declarations-may-only-appear-at-top-level-of-a-m)

[In webpack how do I fix 'import declarations may only appear at top level of a module'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023369/in-webpack-how-do-i-fix-import-declarations-may-only-appear-at-top-level-of-a-m)

But i'm not able to implement a solution

below are the steps i followed.

1) Installed crypto-js using type
--> npm install --save @types/crypto-js

2) Then in my service added reference. Below is the service file

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts" />

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';

import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

@Injectable()
export class AppLocalStorageService {

    constructor(public localStorageService: LocalStorageService) { }

    public setItem(key:any,value:any) {

        var enc = CryptoJS.MD5(key);
        console.log(enc);

    }

    public getItem(key:any) {
        return key;


    }

}
```

Still getting the error.Anything else i should do?

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone guide me to the correct way to integrate crypto-js with angular 4?

Comment: did you get any  solution for this? I am also facing the same.

Answer (score 2):

For my scenario it was ionic appication, i faced the same issue while using typings. After some research i found that instead of typings it is best to use @type. So i used below npm package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/crypto-js

After that i imported the module as below

import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

Hope it will work for you.

Enjoy your coding :)