# import (import one from "./two") is not working in js file ( laravel 5.4 broadcasting Pusher)

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel-5, pusher

Node Version 8.6.0

npm version 5.3.0

Chrome Error ( Version 61.0.3163.100 )

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Mozila Error ( Version 56.0 (64-bit) )

SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
import one from "./two";

Comment: Debug output not a valid question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In webpack how do I fix 'import declarations may only appear at top level of a module'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023369/in-webpack-how-do-i-fix-import-declarations-may-only-appear-at-top-level-of-a-m)

Answer (score 0):

`import` is an ES6 feature. To use ES6 features you need to install babel. Babel is a transpiler, which translates ES6 to ES5 for the browser to understand.

Run the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

add following to your .babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Comment: trying adding babel config in your package.json like this:

"babel": {
    // my babel config here
  }

Or you can create .babelrc file in the root directory of your project