# How to import a component in Vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm really confused about importing a VueJs component.

I'm using Vuejs 2.2.4, and I need to import a Vuejs component. Here is my `app.js`:

```js
Vue.component('Test', require('./Test.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-app',
});
```

*Assume `app.js` is located in `MyProject/js/app.js`*

And here is my component `SimpleCompnent.vue` :

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Simple Component</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        I'm an Simple component!
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Simple Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

*Assume `SimpleCompnent.vue` is located in `MyProject/js/SimpleCompnent.vue`*

Seems like Vue can't load the component! It throws this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `require` cannot be used in a browser context without proper support, so you have couple of options:

- Create (or fix) support for require.js in your app (see how [here](http://requirejs.org/)). As a first step, make sure you have a script tag that fetches require.js and has a `data-main` attribute that points to your app's entrypoint.
- Use a CommonJS implementation for the client, like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [browserify](https://browserify.org/), so `require`s can be written naturally in client-side code.
- Use another module system implementation, e.g. on top of system.js or ES2015.

Either way, if you chose an implementation that uses `import`s (i.e. an ES2015 module system), you may want to use [a transpiler](https://babeljs.io/) that down-compiles your code to a language level the browser supports (avoiding those nasty `Unexpected token import` errors).

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
import Test from './Test.vue'
```

You can see an example of it [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/blob/f7fa3461974e5275b4c5df174b78f9d4a9d579d6/src/components/ItemList.vue#L24).

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

Comment: @HamedKamrava You may need babel, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33440405/1610034), you can also check the setup of [vue-hackernews-2.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0/) as a vue project.

Comment: Link down... :(

Comment: @jdstaerk Updated.

Comment: @Saurabh you're my hero :)