# Babel JS -- simply convert JavaScript STRING to es5 (USING nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I've been googling a lot and found a lot of half-answers or answers that don't address my question, so:

I'm just trying to take an input **string**, that string being regular-source javascript code (NOT nodejs, JUST regular JavaScript) and convert that into another STRING (**not a file**) that contains browser-compatible JavaScript (es5 or whatever).

I'm NOT trying to run nodejs as es5, and I'm not trying to convert a single file, I want to take a **string** of newer JavaScript and get a **string** of older JavaScript.

Now, using the [BabelJS docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/), it says to do this:

```
babel.transform(code, options, function(err, result) {
  result; // => { code, map, ast }
});
```

After making a .babelrc file with this in it (and npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev):

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

But on the docs it doesn't say what "options" should be **just to get it working**.

A bunch of other posts on here said to include `npm install babel-preset-es2015` and

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015'
      }
    ]
  }
```

But I think that's for an older version which doesn't work anymore

and [this famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440405/babel-file-is-copied-without-being-transformed) gives this as a solution:

> ```
> npm install babel-preset-env
> ```
>
> and run
>
> ```
> babel --presets env proxy.js --out-file proxified.js
> ```
>
> or create a .babelrc file containing
>
> ```
> {
>     "presets": [
>         "env"
>     ]
> }
> ```
>
> and run it just like you were before.
>
> env in this case is a preset which basically says to compile all
>   standard ES* behavior to ES5. If you are using Node versions that
>   support some ES6, you may want to consider doing
>
> ```
> {
>     "presets": [
>         ["env", { "targets": { "node": "true" } }],
>     ]
> }
> ```

But that's just making a new javascript FILE I just simply want to make a string from another string.

I think I need to use Babel 7 as that's the newest version, but I keep getting various console errors..

Can someone just provide a simple step-by-step process for getting babel (preferably 7) to convert a **string** of newer JavaScript to a **string** of older?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain if this is what you've expected.

I have this simple project structure:

```
-- package.json
-- index.js
-- .babelrc
```

**index.js**

```
let babel = require('@babel/core')

// some es6 code
let code = `
    let a = () => { console.log('hello') }
`
babel.transform(
    code,
    {
        babelrc: true,
        filename: '.babelrc'
    },
    function(err, result) {
        console.log(result.code)
    }
)
```

and this is the console output:

```
D:\Documents\code\test>node index.js
"use strict";

var a = function a() {
  console.log('hello');
};

D:\Documents\code\test>
```

and my `.babelrc` & `package.json` files in case you're interested.

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

I just followed along the usage guide. In this case, `polyfill` and `cli` are not required.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh that's cool, I just didn't know you can include the babelrc in the options