# How to eval es6 code from NodeJS at runtime with Babel?

Tags: node.js, transform, babeljs

I'm trying to build a nodeJS tool to help me analyzing another AngularJS source code. 
The idea is to :

- read some of the angular project javascript files
- for each file, grab the content
- `eval` the content from the file
- do some stuff

The problem I'm facing is that my Angular source code uses es6 features like `import`, `export`, `arrow functions`, ...Etc. and I using nodeJS which does not support these features yet.

So I tried to use `@babel/core` `transform()` from my Node app code, but it doesn't work. I keep getting error like `Unexpected identifier` which means it doesn't understand the `import {stuff} from 'here';` syntaxe.

```
srcFiles.forEach(content => {
     try {
       (function() {
         eval(require("@babel/core").transform(content.text).code)
        }.call(window, angular));
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  });
```

An sample test file :

```
import _ from 'loadash';

console.log("I'm a file with import and export");

export const = 42;
```

Any idea how I can get this stuff working ? Or maybe another approach ?

Answer (score -1):

You can pass options as the second parameter of `transform` method. See examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55277148/babel-js-simply-convert-javascript-string-to-es5-using-nodejs)